# Convert a nested JSON string to Pandas dataframes (and add "foreign key" to relate them)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have a CSV file which contains the following columns:

- `customer_id`: precisely that.
- `report_date`: the date of creation of the report.
- `json_report`: a JSON object

The JSON object is something like this:

```json
{
    "Person": {
         "Name": {
              "FirstName": "John",
              "LastName": "Doe"
          },
          "Accounts": {
              "Account": [
                   {"AccountNumber":123, "AccountStatus": "G"},
                   {"AccountNumber":137, "AccountStatus": "B"},
                   {"AccountNumber":593, "AccountStatus": "VB"}
              ]
          },
          "Alerts": {
              "Alert": [
                  {"DT":"20200601", "Msg": "Lorem ipsum"},
                  {"DT":"20200615", "Msg": "Dolor sit amet", "Msg2": "Lorem"}
              ]
          }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are nested JSON objects and lists within this object. Moreover, other rows in the original CSV file may have more elements neted inside the JSON file.

What I need is to create Pandas Dataframes that can be related to each other. Following the above example, I'd need the following dataframes:

- `Name`, with columns:

  - `customer_id`
  - `report_date'
  - `FirstName`
  - `LastName`
- `Accounts`, with columns:

  - `customer_id`
  - `report_date'
  - `AccountNumber`
  - `AccountStatus`
- `Alerts`

  - `customer_id`
  - `report_date'
  - `DT`
  - `Msg`
  - `Msg2`

So far, I've been dealing with this problem manually, identifying the nested objects within the JSON object and dealing with them accordingly; however, I know that at some point in the future this won't be sustainable.

So, my question is: **Is there a way to automate this task?**

---

What I've been doing so far:

1. I read the CSV file as a Pandas Dataframe
2. I iterate over each row, reading the `customer_id`, the `report_date` and the `json_report`
3. I convert the JSON report to a dictionary
4. I get the relevant nested objects.

   - If the nested object is a dictionary (e.g. `Name`), I add the `customer_id` and `report_date` key-value pairs, and add the edited dictionary to a list (e.g. `lst_names`)
   - If the nested object is a list (e.g. `Accounts/Account`, I add the `customer_id` and `report_date` key-value pairs to each nested dictionary, and then I add each dictionary to a list (e.g. `lst_accounts`).
5. I convert each list to a Pandas Dataframe

It is important that I have multiple dataframes, since I need each one to perform a different task (i.e. I don't want to use `json_normalize` if possible).

Answer (score 1):

- The easiest thing to do is read in the csv and update the JSON data with the extra information.
- There's a lot of unnecessary complexity, that can be removed, to make dealing with the JSON easier.

### Update the JSON data

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# read in the csv file
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))

# alter the json and create a list of only the json, which now contains all the information
new_json = list()
for i, (idx, date, json) in enumerate(data):
    if i > 0:
        json = literal_eval(json)  # convert the str to a dict
        json['id'] = idx  # add unique id
        json['date'] = date  # add report date
        json['Accounts'] = json['Person']['Accounts']['Account']  # move list to top level key
        json['Alerts'] = json['Person']['Alerts']['Alert']  # move list to top level key
        json['first_name'] = json['Person']['Name']['FirstName']   # move value to top level key
        json['last_name'] = json['Person']['Name']['LastName']   # move value to top level key
        json.pop('Person')  # remove because it's no longer needed
        new_json.append(json)  # append to list

# print(new_json[0])
{'Accounts': [{'AccountNumber': 123, 'AccountStatus': 'G'},
              {'AccountNumber': 137, 'AccountStatus': 'B'},
              {'AccountNumber': 593, 'AccountStatus': 'VB'}],
 'Alerts': [{'DT': '20200601', 'Msg': 'Lorem ipsum'},
            {'DT': '20200615', 'Msg': 'Dolor sit amet', 'Msg2': 'Lorem'}],
 'date': '20200601',
 'first_name': 'John1',
 'id': '123',
 'last_name': 'Doe1'}
```

### Create separate dataframes

```py
# create accounts
accounts = pd.json_normalize(new_json, ['Accounts'], ['id', 'date'])

# display(accounts.head())
   AccountNumber AccountStatus   id      date
0            123             G  123  20200601
1            137             B  123  20200601
2            593            VB  123  20200601
3            123             G  456  20200602
4            137             B  456  20200602

# create alerts
alerts = pd.json_normalize(new_json, ['Alerts'], ['id', 'date'])

# display(alerts.head())
         DT             Msg   Msg2   id      date
0  20200601     Lorem ipsum    NaN  123  20200601
1  20200615  Dolor sit amet  Lorem  123  20200601
2  20200601     Lorem ipsum    NaN  456  20200602
3  20200615  Dolor sit amet  Lorem  456  20200602
4  20200601     Lorem ipsum    NaN  789  20200603

# create name
name = pd.json_normalize(new_json).drop(columns=['Accounts', 'Alerts'])

# display(name)
    id      date first_name last_name
0  123  20200601      John1      Doe1
1  456  20200602      John2      Doe2
2  789  20200603      John3      Doe3
3  123  20200606      John1      Doe1
```

### Data used in `test.csv`:

```py
id;date;json
123;20200601;{"Person": {"Name": {"FirstName": "John1", "LastName": "Doe1"}, "Accounts": {"Account": [{"AccountNumber":123, "AccountStatus": "G"}, {"AccountNumber":137, "AccountStatus": "B"}, {"AccountNumber":593, "AccountStatus": "VB"}]}, "Alerts": {"Alert": [{"DT":"20200601", "Msg": "Lorem ipsum"}, {"DT":"20200615", "Msg": "Dolor sit amet", "Msg2": "Lorem"}]}}}
456;20200602;{"Person": {"Name": {"FirstName": "John2", "LastName": "Doe2"}, "Accounts": {"Account": [{"AccountNumber":123, "AccountStatus": "G"}, {"AccountNumber":137, "AccountStatus": "B"}, {"AccountNumber":593, "AccountStatus": "VB"}]}, "Alerts": {"Alert": [{"DT":"20200601", "Msg": "Lorem ipsum"}, {"DT":"20200615", "Msg": "Dolor sit amet", "Msg2": "Lorem"}]}}}
789;20200603;{"Person": {"Name": {"FirstName": "John3", "LastName": "Doe3"}, "Accounts": {"Account": [{"AccountNumber":123, "AccountStatus": "G"}, {"AccountNumber":137, "AccountStatus": "B"}, {"AccountNumber":593, "AccountStatus": "VB"}]}, "Alerts": {"Alert": [{"DT":"20200601", "Msg": "Lorem ipsum"}, {"DT":"20200615", "Msg": "Dolor sit amet", "Msg2": "Lorem"}]}}}
123;20200606;{"Person": {"Name": {"FirstName": "John1", "LastName": "Doe1"}, "Accounts": {"Account": [{"AccountNumber":123, "AccountStatus": "G"}, {"AccountNumber":137, "AccountStatus": "B"}, {"AccountNumber":593, "AccountStatus": "VB"}]}, "Alerts": {"Alert": [{"DT":"20200601", "Msg": "Lorem ipsum"}, {"DT":"20200615", "Msg": "Dolor sit amet", "Msg2": "Lorem"}]}}}
```

### As a function

```py
from typing import List, Tuple  # used for type hints
import csv
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval


def fix_json(data: List[List[str]]) -> List[dict]:
    new_json = list()
    for i, (idx, date, json) in enumerate(data):
        if i > 0:
            json = literal_eval(json)
            json['id'] = idx
            json['date'] = date
            json['Accounts'] = json['Person']['Accounts']['Account']
            json['Alerts'] = json['Person']['Alerts']['Alert']
            json['first_name'] = json['Person']['Name']['FirstName']
            json['last_name'] = json['Person']['Name']['LastName']
            json.pop('Person')
            new_json.append(json)
            
    return new_json


def make_dataframes(file_path_name: str) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame]:
    with open(file_path_name, 'r') as f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))
        
    new_json = fix_json(data)
    
    accounts = pd.json_normalize(new_json, ['Accounts'], ['id', 'date'])
    alerts = pd.json_normalize(new_json, ['Alerts'], ['id', 'date'])
    names = pd.json_normalize(new_json).drop(columns=['Accounts', 'Alerts'])
    
    return accounts, alerts, names


# function call
accounts, alerts, names = make_dataframes('test.csv')
```